# Is there a way to stack suggested actions be vertically stacked in bot framework?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am using the bot framework v4 SDK for webchat. I have used suggested actions for the choice prompt. By default, the suggested actions are aligned horizontally.

Is there a way to stack suggested actions to be vertically stacked instead of Horizontally in the bot framework?

Comment: Do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your styleOptions and pass it in webchat:

```
suggestedActionLayout: 'stacked', // either "carousel" or "stacked"
```

More on styling the webchat client can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-webchat-customization?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)